# dpdk-pktgen: How to change rate of packet transmission?

Tags: dpdk, ovs-dpdk

I am new to dpdk-pktgen and dpdk in general. My scenario is to test throughput of openvswitch-dpdk at different rates of transmission. I am using dpdk-pktgen version 22.04.1 inside a docker container. Pktgen is using the dpdkvhostuser ports that I created for OVS. I want to change the rate I want to transmit traffic, like at 1 Mpps or 5 Gbits/s suppose. However I am unable to understand with the pktgen CLI commands available, on how to do that.
If anyone knows please could you kindly give me a detailed explanation on it.

Thanks!

Comment: @RahonBose, the answer to the query is shared. Please read and try the same out. If it has helped Accept and upvote to close the question too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always recommend [pktgen document](https://pktgen-dpdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands.html) to understand how to use Pktgen CLI. As per Pktgen

1. `set <portlist> rate <percent>      - Packet rate in percentage` - controls the rate.
2. `set <portlist> burst <value>       - number of packets in a burst` - controls the numbers of packets per burst.

So for the question `I want to change the rate I want to transmit traffic, like at 1 Mpps or 5 Gbits/s suppose`; one needs to use `set [port] rate [% of actual link speed]` and `set [port] burst [1-128]` to control the TX packets per second.

Example: if one needs to send 1Gbps over VHOST-USER Interface, the easiest cli configuration is to use `set all burst 10`. now to have precise Packets one might need to use packets per burst `set all burst 1`.